# Intellisense does not work visual studio code in OSX Yosemite

Tags: visual-studio-code

The intellisense does not work visual studio code in OSX Yosemite. Are there any specific steps to debug this issue?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in Mavericks, either.

Comment: What language(s) are you using within Visual Studio Code that has the issue? I can test if you provide a few more specifics.

Comment: I'm using C#. I downloaded Visual Studio Code and opened the aspnet home repo available here. Noticed that the intellisense does not work - https://github.com/aspnet/home

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open a folder that contains multiple projects, such as the aspnet/Home repo, you would first need to pick a project:

[image: OmniSharp pick a project]